# SQL Server Exception

Tags: sql-server, firewall

My requirement is simple: I have an appserver - WAS 6.1 connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have configured data source for the SQL server using the installation scripts in linux.

When I deployed EAR and try to hit application url, I get the below error while connecting to SQL Server.

```
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed..CWWRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:67)
```

The setup is working for another server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After a long wait, the issue got resolved. There is nothing to do with the EAR. The SSL encryption was enabled in SQL server settings. Just disable the settings did let me establish connection from application to the SQL server.